# Cluster point. Accumulation point.

Tags: limits

Find cluster point of the $A=\{ (x,y):x^{2}+y^{2}=\frac{n+1}{n}, n \in  \mathbf{N}\}$ in $\mathbf{R}^{2}$.

Is the answer:  $\{(x,y): x^{2}+y^{2}=1\}$.

Comment: $A$, minus $\{(0,0)\}$ (if $n=0$ is allowed) plus the unit circle.

Comment: Yes

given $r>0$ there is $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $|\frac{n}{n+1}-1|=\frac{1}{n+1}<r$ whenever $n \geq N$.

Comment: What is your definition of a cluster point?  By the usual definition (assuming this is the same as a "limit point"), every point in $A$ (except possibly $(0,0)$) would also be a cluster point.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom The standard definition (please correct me if I'm wrong) is that cluster point = accumulation point, i.e. $x$ is a cluster point of a sequence $x_n$ if for every neighboorhood $U$ of $x$ there exist infinitely many natural numbers $n$ such that $x_n \in U$. With this definition we are left with only the unit circle. But I guess there are different defintions out there.

Answer (score 0):

You can imagine a bunch of concenctric circles around the origin whose radii are $1-\frac 1n$ for $n \in \{ 1,2,\cdots \}$. If $(x,y) = (r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta) \in A$, you can choose  a sequence $\theta_n \neq \theta$ such that $\theta_n \to \theta$, so that $(r \cos \theta_n, r \sin \theta_n) \to (x,y)$ by continuity of $\cos$ and $\sin$. So $A \subseteq A'$ (where $A'$ denotes the set of cluster points of $A$).

Additionally, if $p = (x,y) = (\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$, then $p_n = ((1-1/n)x,(1-1/n)y)$ is a sequence of points of $A$ not equal to $p$ which converges to $p$, so the unit circle is also a subset of $A'$.

(I assumed $0 \notin \mathbb N$ in the way you wrote the question ; if you assume $0 \in \mathbb N$, notice that $(0,0) \notin A'$ because it is an isolated point of $A$).

So so far any point with distance $1 - \frac 1n$ or $1$ from the origin belongs to $A'$. Otherwise, the set
$$
\{ (r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta) \in \mathbb R^2 \, | \, \theta \in [0,2\pi], r > 0, r \neq 1, r \neq 1-1/n \}
$$
is open and does not intersect $A$, so any point in there does not belong to $A'$. This characterizes $A'$.

Hope that helps,